# How to Output an array from ajax to the ckeditor plugin

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

there is [this plugin.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjZOmp)

ajax request, get the data I need.
I need to take values ​​from success, this:

```js
data[key][1] 
data[key][0]
```

Now data from `tenant_fields` is taken.

Need help, preferably code. The brain is already exploding((

Comment: please update yor code example is not working missing library, CKEDITOR is not known

Comment: I do not know how to add ckeditor in codepen with this plugin

Comment: can you tell which version?

Comment: version ckeditor 4.7.0

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yqMQLe use this codeopen, i attached the ckeditor version 4.7.0, please verify the url reqeust.
so far i see you need 
data = JSON.stringify(data);

Comment: entered this into the ajax request console.log(data) http://piccy.info/view3/12502384/7fb9037be5b4582393f15569037f2141/  and in ckeditor inserted undefined. Before your code, I entered colsole.log(data) and got it http://piccy.info/view3/12502394/7f2f9d9e8ce07e665a64e1311c87574f/ and for some reason the list displays one name, but there are two

Comment: there can be a problem here abbr.setText( dialog.getValueOf( 'tab1', 'tenant_dropdown' ) ); I understand it badly((